java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils\tat
I recently implemented the IAM authentication to some of my microservices but I the problem is that a couple of them throwing this error:

[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread]: [Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | ccproducer':java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils\tat com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:56)\tat com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsResponse(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:46)\tat com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:112)\tat com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:68)\tat com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:165)\tat com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.getCredentials(EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.java:75)\tat com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)\tat com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)\tat software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.internals.MSKCredentialProvider.loadCredentialsWithRetry(MSKCredentialProvider.java:145)\tat software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.internals.MSKCredentialProvider.getCredentials(MSKCredentialProvider.java:132)\tat software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler.handleCallback(IAMClientCallbackHandler.java:100)\tat software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler.handle(IAMClientCallbackHandler.java:77)\tat software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.internals.IAMSaslClient.generateClientMessage(IAMSaslClient.java:138)\tat software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.internals.IAMSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(IAMSaslClient.java:95)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.lambda$createSaslToken$1(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:466)\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\tat java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:466)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendSaslClientToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:373)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.sendInitialToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:292)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:232)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:173)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:547)\tat org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:335)\tat org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:244)\tat

And cannot really find a clue why this happens for some and not for others.
Here is the also external libraries

Have you ever seen something similar to this?
